# BASH - log into a server and then another server

Tags: bash, ssh, eof

I'm writing a script to log into a gateway server and from the gateway server to the nodes that only have access through the gateway

My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cool () {
    ssh -A SERVER << EOF
    ls -l
EOF
}


fool () {
    ssh -A GATEWAY << EOF
        touch foobar
        $(cool)
EOF
}

export -f cool
export -f fool

fool
```

So what ends up happening is that I log into the GATEWAY, and run a few commands. 
Then when I call the function "cool" to ssh into the node, it does that but then starts reading the message from the splash screen and executing the command which is incorrect. 
I want it to execute "ls -l" in the function cool!

Oh and getting rid of the splash screen isn't an option!

Comment: "*then starts reading the message from the splash screen and executing the command which is incorrect*" - what? What is "the splash screen" and what is "the command" you're referring to?

Comment: When I log into the SERVER, there is a spalsh screen <comment> that tells me the last time I logged into that server;

Comment: the command that I want it to run is "ls -l" but it start executing the "Your last login....."

Comment: What happens if you change `$(cool)` to `cool`?

Comment: -bash: line 5: cool: command not found

Comment: basically, it doesn't recognize it as a function

Comment: What happens if you change it to `( cool )`?

Answer (score 0):

## How to do proxying in SSH

I am assuming you set up pubkey authentication, so you don't need to write passwords. SSH has very nice features for proxying and if you create a configuration file in `~/.ssh/config`, it works very nice:

```
Host SERVER
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p GATEWAY
```

then you can connect to the server using single command `ssh SERVER`. If you need to execute some commands, add it after that `ssh SERVER "ls -l"`.

## How to fix your bugs

The scope of your function `cool` is limited to your script and therefore it is not recognized in the `HEREDOC` piped into the second `ssh`. If you want to use a function in the second shell, you need to define it in its scope.

Also calling the function as `$(cool)` runs the function in subprocess, which is something you don't want. You want to call the function directly.

```
#!/bin/bash
fool () {
    ssh -A GATEWAY << EOF
        cool () {
            ssh -A SERVER << EOF2
            ls -l
EOF2
        }
        touch foobar
        cool
EOF
}

export -f fool

fool
```

Comment: This is the solution is the *only* thing you want to so on GATEWAY is log into SERVER, but that isn't the case here.

Comment: @chepner yes, this is solution, how to do that correctly, not how to fix basic issues in the `bash` OPs code. But yes, it would be better to try to fix it too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you generally cannot export functions (or anything) over the `ssh` connection. If you want to run a function on the remote host, it needs to be defined there.

```
#!/bin/bash


fool () {
    ssh -A GATEWAY << EOF
        touch foobar
        cool () {
            ssh -A SERVER <<EOF2
                 ls -l
EOF2
        }
        cool
EOF
}

fool
```